# Identify number of conditions in a dynamic LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq

I've opted to implement the [`System.Linq.Dynamic`](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions#dynamic-expression-api) namespace into my project where I rely on dynamically invoking LINQ expressions from a string against my underlying objects. This allows for highly configurable criteria at the data level.

```
string expression = "x.Client == 100 && x.Insurers.Any(it == 2 || it == 3)";
var x = new MyObject() { Client = 100, Insurers = new int[] { 1, 2 }};   
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyObject), "x");
var e = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p }, null, expression);
bool result = e.Compile().DynamicInvoke(x); // True = condition met
```

My **question** is how do I dynamically identify the number of conditions each string expression contains so that I can give a weight to each expression and choose the one with the highest weight when overlapping occurs. `Regex` *can* work, but there must be something more efficient and practical such as an expression tree.

Ex.:

```
x.Client == 100 // Conditions = 1
x.Client == 100 && x.Insurers.Any(it == 3) // Conditions = 2
x.Client == 100 && x.Insurers.Any(it == 2 || it == 3) // Conditions = 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `System.Linq.Dynamic` library, but assuming it produces normal, strongly typed `Expression` trees you can use an [`ExpressionVisitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor).

This one counts the number of boolean logical operations like `&&`:

```
int CountConditions(Expression expr)
{
    var visitor = new CountBinaryOpsVisitor();
    visitor.Visit(expr);
    return visitor.BinaryOperationCount + 1;
}

class CountBinaryOpsVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public int BinaryOperationCount { get; private set; }

    protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
    {
        switch (node.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.And:
            case ExpressionType.AndAlso:
            case ExpressionType.Or:
            case ExpressionType.OrElse:
            case ExpressionType.ExclusiveOr:
                // Don't count bitwise integer operations, if they are even supported?
                if (node.Left.Type == typeof(bool))
                    BinaryOperationCount++;
                break;
        }
        return base.VisitBinary(node);
    }
}
```

An alternative approach would be to count the number of comparison operators (`==`, `>=` etc.), but I think that would need more complex code to handle boolean expressions like `x.BooleanProp` or `x.Insurers.Any()`.

This implementation doesn't currently count conditional expressions (`x ? y : z`). Not sure how you would factor those into the number of conditions, especially when nested.

Comment: Counting comparison operators should work just as easily as counting logical operators, just a different set of `ExpressionType`s.

Comment: @NetMage The complication I was referring to is that a boolean expression like `x => x.BooleanProperty` doesn't generate any specifc comparison or true-ness expression, it's just a `MemberAccess` or `Call`, etc. So you'd need to tell boolean values apart from other member accesses like `x.Foo.Bar.IntegerProperty`, and then make sure you don't count `x.BooleanExpression == true` twice.

Comment: @kalimag Answers like this make me realize how much more I have yet to learn about C#. Thanks!